# ngRoute não funciona

Tags: angularjs

Eu estava tentando usar ngRoute, mas eu entro no link '/new', aparece um erro que não existe aquele URL e quando entro no normal '/', não mostra nada.

O index.html:

```
<html ng-app="starter">
<head>
    <title>App</title>      
    <link rel="icon" href="m/src/logo.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.0" maximum-scale="1.0" user-scalable="0" name="viewport">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="javascript/text" src="m/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript/text" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript/text" src="m/js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="javascript/text" src="m/js/controller.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

O app.js

```
var app = angular.module("starter", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "templates/main.html"
        })
        .when("/new", {
            templateUrl: "templates/news.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está configurando o Angular para utilizar o modo HTML5:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Você precisa então definir o valor de `base` no cabeçalho da sua página - por exemplo:

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

E também não se esqueça que você precisará mapear as URLs-destino para a base, e isso dependerá do tipo de servidor que você está utilizando. No IIS, por exemplo, você pode utilizar [UrlRewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode).